# How can I set country URL RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Previously my website had URLs for countries; for example: `www.abc.com/uk`, `www.abc.com/us`, `www.abc.com/cn`.

But now my URL structure has changed to a longer form. For example: `www.abc.com/united-kingdom`, `www.abc.com/united-states`, `www.abc.com/china`.

How can I set RewriteRule in `.htaccess` so that the old URL will redirect to the new one?

Comment: Please only tag with tags that likely bring the right experts to your question. Experts about countries are likely out-of-place on StackOverflow and not likely to be able to help. "url" is very broad. You could possible tag with [url-rewriting], but the 3 tags that are left over mostly cover that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your /.htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^uk/?$ http://www.example.com/united-kingdom [R,L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^us/?$ http://www.example.com/united-states [R,L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^cn/?$ http://www.example.com/china [R,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

[RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) is an excellent solution for this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteMap countrymap "txt:/path/to/countrymap.txt"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ /${countrymap:$1} [R,NC,L]
```

Then in your `path/to/countrymap.txt`:

```
uk united-kingdom
us united-states
cn china
```

If you want to replace **http://www.example.com/uk/something** with **http://www.example.com/united-kingdom/something**, then use the following rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /${countrymap:$1}/$2 [R,NC,L]
```

To make your redirect permanent, change `R` to `R=301`.